# Does implementing twitter bootstrap affect already existing css or form?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I just discovered the bootstrap and I'm trying to implement it into my small webpage/app so that I can make my form/console box more visually appealing.

After integrating bootstrap as an external resource in jsfiddle, the prototype of my app/page still works. See:

```
code to make the red box go away
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/L3WyW/4/)

As you can see, the jsfiddle version of my app is working properly

But when implementing bootstrap into the actual site, everything is out of wack...

[Actual site](http://www.abveaspirations.com/)

As you can see, the main image and output of text is completely gone and the structure of the form/console is also gone.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Am I integrating the CSS file incorrectly or am I just implementing bootstrap incorrectly, in general? Here's some the of the HTML file uploaded to the server:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
...
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="textualizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or does it have something to do with the CSS selectors and maybe they get altered after integrating bootstrap and that's why it's not working in the actual site? I'm totally lost here as to why it works in the jsfiddle but not with the actual site. (usually when I'm completely lost on something of this magnitude, the answer ends up being the most simple thing that I just happen to overlook)....

Comment: You HTML page is not able to find bootstrap css & js files. Check your Developer Console. It's giving a 404 error for these files. Add them and it should work fine for you.

Comment: Did you try to include your custom CSS after the Bootstrap CSS? Any changes?

Comment: in ur bootstrap.css its not containing the correct code its something like html code

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/), it has some markup with css classes to get what you wanted. example, `<div class="container"> </div>`, `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>` etc. It will not get applied automatically to your html page by just adding the css reference. Since you used your custom css styling in jsfiddle it works fine. However, since you have not used your custom css in your website, it will render as plain html markup without any styles.

Hence, please change the markup with bootstrap layout and classes for your website and see the result. If you wish to override colors, etc, you can use a custom css file just after the bootstrap core css file as:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycustomstyle.css">
```

You can make overrides to the bootstrap core styles in mycustomstyle.css file. Just read bootstrap docs thoroughly to get an idea about using it in a website/web application.

Comment: ok so I should probably take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups to see the proper html markup to use...

Comment: And should I disregard the comments above that mention that my bootstrap css file contain nothing or that my HTML page is not able to find the bootstrap css and js files? @ravimallya

Comment: 1st comment: Yes, you should. 2nd comment. No, you have to take care of these comments regarding missing files too.